# Преобразование tuple в аргументы функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, коллекции

Есть функция real_func из модуля:

```
def real_func(FirstVar, *OtherVars)
    # какой-то код

def pre_func(First, *Other):
    # мои преобразования
    real_func(First, Other)
```

Вызывать ее нужно из другой функции pre_func. Как видно, на входе можно подать несколько значений, к примеру 3 штуки. Но если на входе в переменную pre_func я подаю integer, то на входе в real_func идет уже tuple, и функция это не принимает, т.к. сама потом оборачивает OtherVars в tuple. Хорошо видно на примере:

```
def real_func(FirstVar, *OtherVars):
        print("-- real func --")
        print("%s is %s" % (FirstVar, type(FirstVar)))
        print("%s is %s" % (OtherVars, type(OtherVars)))
        print("%s is %s" % (OtherVars[0], type(OtherVars[0])))

def pre_func(First, *Other):
        print("-- pre func --")
        print("%s is %s" % (First, type(First)))
        print("%s is %s" % (Other, type(Other)))
        real_func(First, Other)

pre_func(1, 2, 3)
```

Вывод:

```
-- pre func --
1 is <class 'int'>
(2, 3) is <class 'tuple'>
-- real func --
1 is <class 'int'>
((2, 3),) is <class 'tuple'>
(2, 3) is <class 'tuple'>
```

- Я не могу менять код `real_func` - здесь это пример. Реальная функция же падает с ошибкой, т.к. не понимает `tuple` в `tuple`.

У меня никак не получается передать в `real_func` значения типа integer, а не tuple. Надеюсь на помощь.

Comment: Знаете почему редактор стека выделил ваши аргументы? :) Потому что в синтаксисе питона словами с первой буквой в верхнем регистре называются `классы`

Comment: Хорошо. И спасибо за ответ - оказалось все элементарно. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто добавьте `*` перед коллекцией, чтобы распаковать ее в аргументы функции:

```
real_func(First, *Other)
```